# Is creating a news website to earn from AdSense halal?

Tags: halal-haram, work, internet

I am a professional blogger and earning from AdSense. I am going to start a news blog but before starting it I want to know whether sharing news like political news, sports news, weather news, hacking news, tech news and other local news is halal or haram. I will also share images in these news and video to if needed.

I want to know if I started this blog/website and I earned via Adsense from this blog whether it is haram or halal for me?

Comment: Just type website in the search and you will find many answers on your question,

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a news website, then it should be ok. But if you're making the website to spread lies and corruption, then it is haram.

Comment: and how about pictures of politicians , players , athletes etc ?

Comment: What about them ?!!!